# Combining Monthly and Quarterly Data

Tags: statistics, stata

I have a large amount of small data sets that all describe certain aspects of the tourism industry in New Zealand. What they all have in common is regional and year coding.

However, not all the data have the same frequencies. Some data are recorded as monthly and some data are reported as quarterly.

Now I know on SAS there is the EXPAND function to interpolate monthly values from quarterly data, and I was wondering if there was an equivalent command in Stata? And whether you would recommend to use it?

Because the thing is, that all these data are available quarterly, but I'm thinking of using an estimation procedure that is very degree of freedom intensive, so I want all the observations I can get.

Comment: There are methodology that allows you to do regression when the regressor and regressand are of different frequency incase you are not aware of.

Comment: A quick Google search turned up an article on [cubic spline interpolation](http://columbiaeconomics.com/2010/01/20/how-economists-convert-quarterly-data-into-monthly-cubic-spline-interpolation/) with a sample .do file that interpolates monthly values from quarterly data.  I'll let the other posters' comments speak to the question of whether you should do this, however.

Comment: Interpolation is perhaps most often used to fill in occasional gaps in data or to map from an irregular grid to a regular one. But there are several commands: `ipolate` (official), `cipolate` (SSC), `csipolate` (SSC), `nnipolate` (SSC), `pchipolate`. But the gain in df would be largely spurious.

Answer (score 2):

???

That's three question marks, but it doesn't really differ in information from one.

Stata has an `expand` command so in principle you could just get 3 copies of each quarterly value. In practice, you would be kidding yourself if you thought you had 3 times as much information, no more than answering who is buried in Grant's tomb three times with the same name would be more informative.

There is one important exception to this harsh answer. Type `ssc desc denton` to learn about 
a method to extend coarse series to fine series, provided that you have fine data to use as a basis for the expansion.

Comment: Here's another way to look at it. Take any existing dataset which you like to be bigger. You could copy every observation several times, but there would be precisely no extra information.